# $unset 2D array MongoDB (C#)

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, nosql

Good Morning,

I have a Issue With MongoDb, i'm trying to unset an index of "citations", on my Json you can see 1 field citations with 2 citation : "Saisir ou Selection une citations" and "XD", i'd like to unset XD, how can i achieve this ?

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("604ca13de0059b65e4e67c01"), 
"username" : "LOL", 
"pass" : "LOL", 
"citations" : [
    [
        {
            "body" : "Saisir ou Selection une citations", 
            "author" : "author", 
            "oeuvre" : "oeuvre", 
            "annee" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "body" : "XD", 
            "author" : "XD", 
            "oeuvre" : "XD", 
            "annee" : NumberInt(3)
        }
    ]
]
```

}

I've tried Many things :

```
db.getCollection("Users").update(
{}, {$unset : {"citations.$.body" : "XD"}}
)
```

and I tried many other variant but i didnt found the right Solution.

PS :

I'm working on a C# Wpf APP, it's would be perfect if you can help me on this langage but otherwise no worries it is not very different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use the `ElemMatch` and `PullFilter` operators in the c# driver to achieve your goal like so:

```cs
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    u => u.Citations, 
    c => c.Body == "XD");

var update = Builders<User>.Update.PullFilter(
    u => u.Citations,
    c => c.Body == "XD");

await userCollection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

here's another less verbose way to do the same thing using MongoDB.Entities library (which i wrote):

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class User : Entity
    {
        public Citation[] Citations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Citation
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test");

            await new[] {
                new User {
                    Citations = new[]
                    {
                        new Citation { Body = "Saisir ou Selection une citations"},
                        new Citation { Body = "XD"},
                    }
                },
                new User {
                    Citations = new[]
                    {
                        new Citation { Body = "Saisir ou Selection une citations"},
                        new Citation { Body = "XD"},
                    }
                }
            }.SaveAsync();

            await DB.Update<User>()
                    .Match(u => u.Citations.Any(c => c.Body == "XD"))
                    .Modify(f => f.PullFilter(u => u.Citations, c => c.Body == "XD"))
                    .ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, sorry for long time to accept your answer, i'm doing my homeworks only Saturday and Sunday

Comment: my mistake was also ; i had a List<List<citations>> and not a List<citations>

Answer (score 1):

In update function you need to give first conditition. Than you may need to use "$pull" for removing values from array.

It should be something like this:

```
    db.getCollection("Users").update(
      {citations.body: "XD"}, {$pull : {"citations.$.body" : "XD"}}
    )
```

Comment: hmm, your code return this : `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Comment: db.getCollection("Users").update(
      {citations.body: "XD"}, {$pull : {"citations.body" : "XD"}}
    )

What about this?

Comment: Same problem, but on this part of your code : `update( {citations.body: "XD"} ` it does not compile, i have to add quotation mark like this :  `update( {"citations.body": "XD"},` is that normal ?

Comment: Well. Okay. You need to put condition to your update function. Yes, I forgot the quotation marks. It is needed.

  db.getCollection("Users").update(
      {"citations.body": "XD"}, {$set : {"citations.$.body" : ""}}
    )

Comment: still have "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0, it's look like, it's cant found citations.body